# Trigger fancybox in knockout template from component

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I've been using knockout components with some success to refactor an old application (I would use something newer, but we were already using some knockout anyway, so I just expanded that).

Anyway, I'm currently building a knockout component for a session timeout control. It'll load with data using params when the page loads, and will let them know when their session is about to timeout so they can renew. However, I've got a bit of an issue in that to replace the functionality I'm trying to replace, I need to somehow trigger a fancybox and target the div that is the root of the template for this component. I can easily do it just by ID, but I was wondering if there was some more eloquent way to do it (like if there was a variable in scope that represented the bound template or something). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no eloquent/already implemented way (see https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1483).

One way you can solve it, is as you already suggested to add a known ID. A more dynamic way would be to add an ID to the viewmodel and to bind it to the element via `attr: { id: Model.ElementID }`.